# Unable to copy the value of one field to other

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code to copy the value from one field to other, but don't know why its not working.

```
<input name="test" id="test" onkeyup="test(this);" />
<input name="demo" id="demo" readonly />

function test(obj) {
   obj.value = document.getElementById("demo").value();
}
```

Comment: Your javasscript code is wrong, you miss placed the () at the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the value and set it like this,

```
function test(obj) {
   document.getElementById("demo").value = obj.value;
}
```

First, you just need to remove the brackets `()` from value and
second, you are setting the readonly feild value to your first editable field, you need to do the reverse.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/J54VG/